# Disabling DHCP Server

Tags: dhcp

For some strange reason, my Raspberry Pi is acting as the DHCP server on my home network.  Whenever a computer boots up in our house, it's immediately told that the IP address for the DHCP server is my Pi.

I don't know if there's some way to prevent such an assignment outside of static setup (which is what our "main" computer is on now as a workaround), or whether it's something that needs to be done in the router admin page or in the Pi.  I would like to prevent just turning off the Pi because I'm trying to keep it open as a file offload server.

My router - Netgear R6200, firmware V1.0.1.52_1.0.41 - is on 192.168.1.1, and my Pi is on 80 - every other device we own filters in between those two addresses.

Comment: If you're running Raspbian, if you do a `dpkg -l | grep -i dhcp` what do you get ?

Comment: Four entries, one of which is `ii  isc-dhcp-server  4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6` - there's also a `isc-dhcp-client` (which I assume belongs), `isc-dhcp-common` (which I assume is a dependency of the server and the client) and `udhcpd`.

Comment: what Pi OS have you got, Raspian?

Comment: I've got a Raspbian image installed, pre-configured for Jasper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable the DHCP Server so that it doesn't run on startup.

I don't have a box handy at the moment, but this command should do what you need it to do

`sudo update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server disable`

This will stop the dhcp server from running on startup.
If you have both servers installed, you may need to run that twice, replacing `isc-dhcp-server` with `udhcpd` the second time around.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
sudo update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
```

or

```
sudo update-rc.d -f dhcpcd remove
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. what do these commands do?

Comment: Isn't this self-explanatory? It's actually the correct answer for the Raspian Jessie Lite distribution.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the dhcp client daemon (dhcpcd), rather than the dhcp server (dhcpd) that the question asks about?

Answer (score 0):

edit the following in /etc/network/interfaces as

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static 
address <address>    
netmask <netmask>
gateway <gateway>
```

Comment: How does this prevent a DHCP server running on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I am not sure it is preventing DHCP server but It maintains own static address instead of listening to DHCP ip address

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
```

Second solution did not work for me it indeed removes the client and not the server.

Try:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d dhcpd disable && sudo update-rc.d -f dhcpd remove
```

Comment: Note that `update-rc.d` is atavistic and maintained for backward compatibility only.