# avoid dnsmasq to run at boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, dhcp

I have dnsmasq installed to make my Pi 3 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie) into an AP (accesspoint). I want to be able to switch between AP mode and client mode.

This all works fine, but when I boot my pi3 dsnmasq will startup, which I do not want (only for the AP mode).

I removed all links to `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` from `/etc/rc*.d` but it still starts.  I set `ENEABLED=0` in `/etc/default/dnsmasq` but it still starts.

I run systemctl disable dnsmasq.service but it still starts.

Only when I add exit 0 to the start of the /etc/init.d/dnsmasq it will not start, but than I can not start it myself.

So a work arround is changing the script removing the exit 0 start it and than adding the exit 0 to the script again. But this seems not the most elegant way of doing this.

is there a way to find out what is starting dnsmasq?

edit:

i have removed the dnsmasq.service from the service dir:

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dnsmasq.service
```

but still dnsmasq is started:

```
 ps aux | grep dnsmasq
 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
```

to answer the question in the comment:

```
 systemctl list-units | grep dns
 dnsmasq.service loaded active running   dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
```

after disable with systemctl:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl disable dnsmasq
Synchronizing state for dnsmasq.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d dnsmasq defaults
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script    `dnsmasq'      overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `dnsmasq' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: script dnsmasq_run: service dnsmasq already provided!
insserv: script dnsmasq_exit: service dnsmasq already provided!
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d dnsmasq disable
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `dnsmasq' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `dnsmasq' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: script dnsmasq_run: service dnsmasq already provided!
insserv: script dnsmasq_exit: service dnsmasq already provided!
```

there has been a question alike this one ([Disabling DHCP Server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/disabling-dhcp-server))

Comment: *"is there a way to find out what is starting dsnmasq?"* -> You should investigate `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.

Comment: i updated my question and will try systemd-analyze

Comment: You could also check `sudo systemctl list-units | grep dns` to see if it is being run by systemd, in which case removing the links to `init.d` was not effective.  I'm not sure why it would work out that way, but I believe it *could.*

Comment: i added the os version (sorry for that).

Comment: i tried to remove the service like this:
systemctl disable dnsmasq.service

but it did not work

Comment: Since it evidently has a service file, have a look at `systemctl status dnsmasq`.  I think there can be services that it won't truly be disabled if other things *start* them for whatever reason.   Using `systemd-analyze critical-chain dnsmasq.service` might help with that, but more likely it could confirm if something you suspect is starting dnsmasq actually does (such as `dhcp.service` or whatever it is called; you need to use the full name with suffix as shown in `systemclt list-units` with `critical-chain`; with no argument it just shows the default target which is not the whole picture).

Comment: Lemme try that one again: `systemd-analyze critical-chain foobar` will mention `dnsmasq` if `foobar` starts `dnsmasq`, but unfortunately `systemd-analyze critical-chain dnsmasq` probably won't tell you what started it, meaning you have to guess, or find a "critical chain" that includes both of them...

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work now. not 100% what did the trick but i think there were 2 dnsmasq.service files. i removed one and again did the systemctl disable dnsmasq and now it does not start at startup.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.